# How to make AJAX working with select2?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm quite new in AJAX and I'm trying to get results from AJAX request in [select2](https://select2.github.io).

This is my HTML:

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="Airport"><option disabled selected>Airport</option></select>
```

and this is my select2 call:

```
$(function() {
    initAirportList = function(){
        $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
          // minimumInputLength: 2,
          ajax: {
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET",
            url: 'data',
            delay: 250,
          }
        ,});
    }

    initAirportList();
});
```

JSON data is here:

```
[
{id:'ADL',text:'Adelaide, Australia, ADL'},
{id:'MEL',text:'Melbourne, Australia, MEL'},
{id:'PER',text:'Perth, Australia, PER'},
{id:'SYD',text:'Sydney, Australia, SYD'}
]
```

What should I add into the code for the select2 start to show the results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First have a look into the documentation. There is described how to load data from remote resources.

https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax

and

https://select2.github.io/options.html#ajax

I think, you are missing some options in the initialization. 
You have to add the `data` option in your `ajax` request:

```
  ajax: {
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        url: 'data',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
           return {
              q: params.term, // search term
              page: params.page
           };
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I don't really understand what they want to do declaring this `data` and `processResults` arguments. I see that when I click on the `select` box the `json` data are received. But I don't understand how to retrieve them? Without `ajax` the select box works perfectly.